# Xcode error when limiting the amount of Characters allowed in UITextVIew

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitextview

I keep getting two errors in this block of code, which both state "type of expression is ambiguous without more context".
I am following a tutorial, the tutorial uses count(descriptionTextView.text) and i found out this is no longer supported and you must now use text.count instead. Apart from this i have changed nothing from the code block which works in the tutorial.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText 
text: String) -> Bool {
        if range.length + range.location > text.count(descriptionTextView.text) {
            return false
    }
    let newlength = text.count(descriptionTextView.text) + text.count(text) - range.length
    return newlength <= 750
}
```

Line 3 and 6 is where i get both of the errors, anyone know how to make this unambiguous? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be throwing `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'`. `count` is a var, not func

Comment: Instead of `text.count(descriptionTextView.text)` you probably need to use `descriptionTextView.text!.count`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textView.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: text)
    return updatedText.count <= 750
}
```